# Error: Expected ')' before 'packet'

Tags: c, gcc, syntax

I have this code:

```
void addSpammer(honeypot_command_packet packet){
          hashtable_put(spammer_table, packet->ip_source_address_big_endian, packet);
      }
    void addVulnerable( honeypot_command_packet packet){
      hashtable_put(vulnerable_table, packet->udp_dest_port_big_endian, packet);
    }

    void addEvil( honeypot_command_packet packet){
      hashtable_put(evil_table, packet, packet);
    }

    void rmSpammer(honeypot_command_packet packet){
      hashtable_remove(spammer_table, packet->ip_source_address_big_endian);
    }
     
    void rmVulnerable(honeypot_command_packet packet){
      hashtable_remove(vulnerable_table, packet->udp_dest_port_big_endian);
    }

    void rmEvil(honeypot_command_packet packet){
      hashtable_remove(evil_table, packet);
    }

    void print_stats(){
      puts("Printing stats...");
    }

    void handle_packet_table(honeypot_command_packet pack){

            if(pack->secret_big_endian == HONEYPOT_SECRET){
                    
                    printf_m("This is a command packet %x \n", pack->cmd);
                    
                    if(pack->cmd == HONEYPOT_ADD_SPAMMER){
                            // handle addint a spammer
                            addSpammer(pack);
                            
                    }else if(pack->cmd == HONEYPOT_ADD_EVIL){
                            // handle adding an evil packet hash
                             addEvil(pack);
                            
                    }else if(pack->cmd == HONEYPOT_ADD_VULNERABLE){
                            // handle addint a vunlerable port
                            addVulnerable(pack);
                            
                    }else if(pack->cmd == HONEYPOT_DEL_SPAMMER){
                            // handle removing a spammer
                            rmSpammer(ip_source_address_big_endian);
                            
                    }else if(pack->cmd == HONEYPOT_DEL_EVIL ){
                            //handle removing an evil packet
                            rmEvil(ip_source_address_big_endian);
                            
                    }else if(pack->cmd == HONEYPOT_DEL_VULNERABLE ){
                            //handle removing a vulnurable port
                            rmVulnerable(udp_dest_port_big_endian);
                            
                    }else if(pack->cmd == HONEYPOT_PRINT){
                            print_stats();
                            //handle printing from the packet
                    }else{
                            printf_m("there is a problem with the data field \n");
                    }
            
            }
            else{
              // the packet is not anything
              //check if it is in any of the lists then increment the number of packets processed
              void* *item;
              if (hashtable_get(spammer_table, pack->ip_source_address_big_endian, *item) == 0){
                addSpammer(pack);
              }

              if (hashtable_get(vulnerable_table, pack->udp_dest_port_big_endian, *item) == 0){
                addVulnerable(pack);
              }

              if (hashtable_get(evil_table, pack, *item) == 0){
                addEvil(pack);
              }
              else{
                hashtable_put(good_table, pack, pack);
              }
            }

            packets_arrived++;
            bytes_arrived+=sizeof(pack);
    }
```

and I get the following errors:

> network.c:94: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘packet’
>
> network.c:98: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘packet’
>
> network.c:102: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘packet’
>
> network.c:106: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘packet’
>
> network.c:110: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘packet’
>
> network.c:114: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘packet’
>
> network.c:122: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘pack’

I'm not really sure how to fix these issues, I checked that the parens match up already.

Comment: Where is `honeypot_command_packet` defined?

Comment: Without line numbers in your example, it's hard to tell.  Also, there is information about the types you are using.  Please post a minimal example that exhibits the failure.

Comment: These are only 88 lines, right? I might have missed one or two but no more.

Comment: they're all defined and i already included the header files

Comment: You didn't include them here... what you posted here is only consistent with every line which references `honeypot_command_packet` generates an error.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're trying to use the type `honeypot_command_packet`, but you've apparently not defined that type previously.  Perhaps you are missing an `#include` that is needed, or the type needs to be qualified as `some_namespace::hoenypot_command_packet`

Comment: The `c` tag is applied, but not the `c++` tag.  I would presume that namespaces are not the problem.  Lack of an `#include` might be though.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler is confused by `honeypot_command_packet`. @ChrisDodd already answered the question and my answer adds a worked example. I get more MSVC compiler error messages, but the first is like OP's single error messages at every ocurrence of `honeypot_command_packet`.

```
void addEvil(honeypot_command_packet packet) {
}

int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

MSVC Compiler output:

```
test.c
test.c(1) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ')' before identifier 'packet'
test.c(1) : error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'packet'
test.c(1) : error C2059: syntax error : ';'
test.c(1) : error C2059: syntax error : ')'
test.c(1) : error C2449: found '{' at file scope (missing function header?)
test.c(2) : error C2059: syntax error : '}'
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\BIN\cl.EXE"' :return code '0x2'
Stop.
```

But when I add this line

```
typedef char *honeypot_command_packet;
```

it compiles cleanly.